# Loop nested array and return values by index

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nested array that holds a handful of coordinates. I am trying to loop the nested array and log the values of each coordinate.

I can get it working in Python, but I need it in JavaScript. Here is how it works in python:

```
list_of_coordinates = [(100, 98), (200, 78)]
for i in list_of_coordinates:
    x_coord = i[0]
    y_coord = i[1]
    print(x_coord, y_coord)
```

The output of the above is:

```
100 98
200 78
```

When I try to do this in Javascript I get the output of 0 and 1... not the actual coordinate values.

```
let listOfCoordinates = [[100, 0], [200, 1]];
for (const i in listOfCoordinates) {
    let xCoord = i[0];
    let yCoord = i[1];
    console.log(xCoord, yCoord);
}
```

The output of this is

```
0 undefined
1 undefined
```

Comment: `listOrCoordinates.forEach(coord => console.log(coord[0], coord[1]));` would also do the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead as the following:

```js
let listOfCoordinates = [[100, 0], [200, 1]];
for (const i of listOfCoordinates) {
    let xCoord = i[0];
    let yCoord = i[1];
    console.log(xCoord, yCoord);
}
```

See from the documentation:

> The `for...of` statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.

Comment: haha. Amazing. I've spent the past 30mins googling this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Correct way, if you want to continue to use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```js
const listOfCoordinates = [[100, 0], [200, 1]];
for (let i in listOfCoordinates) {
    let xCoord = listOfCoordinates[i][0];
    let yCoord = listOfCoordinates[i][1];
    console.log(xCoord, yCoord);
}
```

Because you named the variable "i", which is often short for "index", I thought you'd want it to be an index, which would use the "in" form.

The [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) form returns the values. It could be written like so:

```js
const listOfCoordinates = [[100, 0], [200, 1]];
    for (let coord of listOfCoordinates) {
        let xCoord = coord[0];
        let yCoord = coord[1];
        console.log(xCoord, yCoord);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` way, with deconstruction of the input.

```js
let listOfCoordinates = [[100, 0], [200, 1]];

listOfCoordinates.forEach(([xCoord, yCoord]) => console.log(xCoord, yCoord));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to the wanted variables.

```js
let listOfCoordinates = [[100, 0], [200, 1]];

for (const [xCoord, yCoord] of listOfCoordinates) {
    console.log(xCoord, yCoord);
}
```